# SSIS script task control flow

Tags: ssis, control-flow, operator-precedence, script-task

I have 3 script tasks : Task1, Task2, and Task3. Now I need a control flow such that if both Task1 and Task2 completes successfully, Task3 should execute. I tried to use Precedence constraint, but don't know how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable "Taskfailed" and set this to 1 in the variable set up.

Put Task1 and Task 2 within a Sequence Container. If both these tasks succeed then set TaskFailed to zero.

Link Task 3 to this container.

Right click on the green arrow between the container and task 3.

Select "Edit"

Evaluation operation "Expresion and constraint"

Value: "Success"
Expression: @Taskfailed==0

So, Task 3 will only execute if task1 and task2 complete successfully

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't use Sequence Container, because I have large number of Script tasks connected with each other. At the end I want to create a Task 3 which should execute if task1 and task2 complete successfully. Do you know any other approach?

Comment: Could you not apply the Expression and constraint between the last task executed and "Task 3"? I presume this is all within a single Control Flow? A little more detail would help!

Comment: Okay. Here is what I mean. Consider that I have 5 script tasks. Task A, Task B, Task C, Task D, and Task E. Now suppose that on the success of Task A, Task B gets executed, and on the success of Task C, Task D gets executed. So I can't put Task B and Task D into Sequence Container. So I need a alternative solution for it. And at the end only if Task B and Task D gets executed successfully, then Task E should get executed. I really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic work flow]
Here's how I think it could work. Excuse the poor quality graphics